# JPA : How to avoid hardcoding jpa-jar location?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

Here's the facts :

1. I have 2 jars that contain JPA entities in my webapp,
2. and entities from one jar (jar A) has references of entities in another jar (jarB)
3. I put the `<jar-file>/WEB-INF/lib/MyJarB.jar</jar-file>` in the persistence.xml of jar A

But i dont want to hardcode the **/WEB-INF/lib/MyJarB.jar** because i could be testing the entities in a test environment, and would love to have another way of specifying entities jar dependencies other than hardcoding the path.

I tried the `<jar-file>MyJarB.jar</jar-file>` and `<jar-file>./MyJarB.jar</jar-file>`, but both failed.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend NOT putting the `persistence.xml` together with your JARs, because the persistence definition is the application concern. Therefore it would be better to have a `persistence.xml` in your **web** module, declaring both JARs:

```
<jar-file>/WEB-INF/lib/MyJarA.jar</jar-file>
<jar-file>/WEB-INF/lib/MyJarB.jar</jar-file>
```

In case you have tests in your web module, and you want to use another persistece definition, just create an alternate persistence.xml, say in `src/test/resources`, and just use that one to instantiate your EntityManagerFactory.

Answer (score 3):

Create another `persistence.xml` for pure testing only and put it in project B itself or another sub-project which contains test classes.